# Не дать выйти курсору за пределы окна

Tags: java, javafx

Хотел сделать 3d игру на javafx.

Как сделать так чтобы курсор не вышла из окно?. Например в таких играх как стрелялки если вы заметили курсор всегда находится в центре окна. Как это делается в javafx?

Comment: а что у вас не получается?

Comment: С помошью мышки я хотел управлять камерой, но курсор выходит из рамки окно

Comment: Я попробовал спрятать курсор но всё равно выходит из рамки программы. scene.setCursor(Cursor.NONE);

Comment: У меня всё получается только надо сделать так чтобы курсор всегда находился внутри программы

Comment: На [StackExchange по gamedev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/111347/setting-the-cursors-location-in-javafx) советуют использовать [Robot->MouseMove](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#mouseMove(int,%20int)) для AWT, чтобы принудительно подвинуть курсор куда надо (в вашем случае в центр окна). Но вообще javafx не предназначен для таких целей.